# Cannot insert duplicate key row in Object dbo.aspnet_Users

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to update the `loweredUsername` to be the user's email address. While trying to run an update statement I am seeing this error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.aspnet_Users' with
>   unique index 'aspnet_Users_Index'. The duplicate key value is
>   (AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-1234A1234a12, test@test.com)

`User_id` column has the primary key.

Here is my update statement

```
update table set LoweredUserName = 'test@test.com' where UserId = 'AAAAAA';
```

UserId is unique in the table. Since I am trying to update the `loweredUserName` I am not sure why its preventing me to do so since the LoweredUserName does not have any relationships with other tables. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It means that `LowerUserName` column already has `test@test.com` value.

Comment: Ah, I cannot believe I did not see that. I appreciate your help @AlexKudryashev

Answer (score 0):

Check the table to make sure there isn't another index which has a unique email. You could just try setting lowered username to test2016@test.com instead of test@test.com.